# Ionic - app works in browser but does not work when emulated in mobile

Tags: php, android, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have tried this code

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
});
})
.controller('datactr',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
$scope.submit=function(){
          console.log("step1");

    $http({
      method:'POST',
      url:'http://awesomeg.2fh.co/updata.php',
      crossDomain : true,
      data:{
        'name':$scope.name,
      }

    }).success(function(data,status,header,config){
      console.log("step2");
      console.log(data);
      $scope.name="";
      $scope.message="You have successfully updated the database";
    })
}
}])
```

my php code on backend

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
    header('Access-Control-Request-Method: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE,     OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *,x-requested-with,Content-Type');
    header('X-Frame-Options: DENY');
 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
 $request = json_decode($postdata);
 $name=$request->name;
 if($name){
 $con=mysqli_connect('host','uname','pass','db');
 $result=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO userdata (name) VALUES ('$name')");
 }
$out=json_encode($name);
echo"$out";
?>
```

My HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="js/services.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">

<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Data Collection</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content ng-controller="datactr">
  <form role="form" ng-submit="submit()">
   <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label item-divider">
      Name

    <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Name">
      </label>
<div class="padding">
      <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">Submit</button>
    </div>
<div class="item item-footer">
      {{message}}
    </div>
 </form>      
  </ion-content>
 </ion-pane>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Well this is basic ionic app which takes data from user and sends it as a json to server, the server recieves the json and then process it to update database at backend.I have tested this on browser using

> ionic serve

it works fine when I input data it updates the database and it gives a message successfully updated but when i tried testing it on mobile using

> ionic run --devices

the app opens in mobile and when I input data and tap submit then nothing happens the screen with filled input field stays.

Can anyone help?

> fixed the issue by adding the following lines:

```
adding cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

and adding the follwoing lines to config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

Comment: You can't use both Allow-Origin: * and Allow-Credentials: true at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that your code throwing an exception in Your devices' webiew. You can use the Chrome developer tools to access the devices' console and another features provided by developer tools in desktop Chrome version.

How to do it:

- Connect Your device to computer,
- Enable the "USB Debugging" option in "Developer" applet of "Settings" menu in Android device,
- type following in Chrome address bar:

  chrome://inspect
- Run your Ionic app at your Android device
- Select Your app in Your "chrome://inspect" screen

You will see the app screen with console and other developer tools.
And there You can follow possible JS exceptions.

Comment: have you solve the issue? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I was using http://url.com then I changed my url to https://url.com and problem solved